# In R ,how to collapse character into new group

Tags: r, if-statement

I R, I want to add new character group 'region_new ', it seems 'if else' not work.
Any one can help ? thank

```
test_data <- data.frame(region=LETTERS)

test_data$region_new <- ''
if (test_data$region in c('a','b','c')){
   test_data$region_new <- 'Level_A'
} else if (test_data$region in c('d','x','z')) {
   test_data$region_new <- 'Level_B'
} else {
   test_data$region_new <- 'Level_Other'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need vectorized `ifelse` instead of `if`/`else`. Also use `%in%` instead of `in`.

You can also use `case_when` from `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
test_data <- data.frame(region=LETTERS)

test_data %>%
  mutate(region_new = case_when(region %in% c('A','B','C') ~ 'Level_A', 
                                region %in% c('D','X','Z') ~ 'Level_B',
                                TRUE ~ 'Level_Other'))
```

Another option is to use `fct_collapse` from `forcats`.

```
test_data %>%
  mutate(region_new = forcats::fct_collapse(region, 
                                   Level_A = c('A','B','C'), 
                                   Level_B = c('D','X','Z'), 
                                   other_level = 'Level_Other'))
```